# Design pattern for file based communication?

Tags: design-patterns, file, communication

I have to extend an existing program (Java-based, but this shouldn't count).
This program should communicate with another program X.

This program X is .. uhm.. a little bit older and supports only file based communication.
This means I have to put my file into some specific folder.
The "answer" is placed in another folder where I have to pick it up.

Are there any design patterns for this kind of communication?
Problems with file-locking, unflushed io-streams etc. come to my mind if I think about it.

Do you have some more descriptive keywords for my googleing? "file based communication" doesn't take it.

Comment: Can you describe more problems? File-locking and unflushed io-streams can be handled using RAII (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe [Producer-Consumer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem) pattern is what you want.

I belive you'll find better articles then the article in wikipedia. But main concepts are described there clear enough (just replace 'buffer' with 'file' for your concrete case).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is possible to create file system watchers in java (like it is in C#), but I do always use a file system watcher to monitor the folder which receives files.